# Can Sacred Fists use Ice Gauntlet/Ice Axe?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, prestige-class

Can a character in the Sacred Fist prestige class use the Ice Gauntlet and Ice Axe spells without violating their vows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Code of Conduct of the prestige class sacred fist (*Complete Divine* 59-61) says that a creature that joins the organization "refuses to use any weapon. A sacred fist who knowingly carries or uses a weapon loses all class spells and features and advances no farther [*sic*] as a sacred fist until he atones." Given the prestige class's class features and rather than assuming the organization forces its members to undergo multiple amputations, this DM assumes that by *weapons* the organization *actually* forbids its members from using and carrying weapons that are *not* natural parts of the member's body. (That is, [*unarmed strike*](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#unarmed-strike) is an entry on Table 7–5: Weapons (*Player's Handbook* 116-17), and even a nonmonk's unarmed strike "may be a punch, kick, [or] head butt" (*PH* 121).)

The 1st-level Clr spell *ice gauntlet* [evoc] (*Spell Compendium* 119) says that the caster "can attack with [his] fist in all respects as if [he] were wearing a *+1 spiked gauntlet*." As attacks with the spell's effect remain attacks with the caster's fist, this DM would rule that a sacred fist could indeed employ the *ice gauntlet* spell's effect yet still remain in good standing with his organization.

However, the 3rd-level Clr spell *ice axe* [evoc] (*SpC* 118) says that the "spell creates a battleaxe-shaped formation of jagged, fast-swirling ice shards in your hand. You are automatically considered proficient with the *ice axe*. Attacks with the *ice axe* are melee touch attacks." The description of the effect and the fact that attacks are made with the actual *ice axe* effect itself combined would see this DM rule that the *ice axe* effect is, in fact, a weapon, and that employing the effect violates the organization's code.

However, in both cases, I recommend asking the DM. [The line between spells and spells that are also weapons is blurry](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50607/8610), and another DM may have a different but totally reasonable reading of the spells or the sacred fist code.

Comment: Better yet, rather than ask the DM, have your character ask a senior monk or his Abbott.

Comment: I think the appearance counts for something as well.

Comment: @nijineko I agree and said so ("The *[visual] description of the [spell's] effect* and the fact that…"), but I guess I could've made that clearer, given that I had to use brackets to explain it. `:-)`

Comment: I was [intending for my statement to be indicating that I was] agreeing with you, as it happens, but I can see how your bracketed addendum would make it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the exact same information (https://dndtools.net/spells/spell-compendium--86/ice-axe--3862/ & https://dndtools.net/spells/spell-compendium--86/ice-gauntlet--3882/) as @Hey I Can Chan, I'd rule the exact opposite.

In my humble opinion the *ice gauntlet* is an armed melee attack doing some extra cold damage, thus forbidden.

The *ice axe* however, is a spell-effect doing cold damage upon a successful touch attack. As it does no melee damage whatsoever, I'd rule this as an unarmed attack.

*edit* +1 for the comment made by @gaynorvader (ask a patron in-game).